# Reset the status of radio buttons in a QGroupBox in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I would like to clear the status of radio buttons in this QGroupBox, however,

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QRadioButton
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGroupBox

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Radio Button Example")

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Labels", self)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(20, 20, 260, 100)

        self.radioButton1 = QRadioButton("Label 1", self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton1.move(10, 20)

        self.radioButton2 = QRadioButton("Label 2", self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton2.move(10, 40)

        self.radioButton3 = QRadioButton("Label 3", self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton3.move(10, 60)

        self.radioButton4 = QRadioButton("Label 4", self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton4.move(10, 80)

        self.toggleButton = QPushButton("Toggle Radio Button", self)
        self.toggleButton.setGeometry(20, 140, 260, 40)
        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(self.toggleRadioButton)

    def toggleRadioButton(self):
        "***This part does not work****"
        self.radioButton1.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton2.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton3.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton4.setChecked(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

How should I do in the toggleRadioButton function so that all the radio button will be unset when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

That worked. Someone may find it useful:

```
def toggleRadioButton(self):
    for radioButton in [self.radioButton1, self.radioButton2, self.radioButton3, self.radioButton4]:
        radioButton.setAutoExclusive(False)
        radioButton.setChecked(False)
        radioButton.setAutoExclusive(True)
```

Answer (score -2):

To clear the status of radio buttons in the toggleRadioButton function, you can use the setChecked(False) method for each radio button. However, in this case, you should use a button group (QButtonGroup) to manage the radio buttons. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QRadioButton
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QButtonGroup

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Radio Button Example")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Labels", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup(self)
        self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)

        self.radioButton1 = QRadioButton("Label 1")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton1)
        self.groupBox.layout().addWidget(self.radioButton1)

        self.radioButton2 = QRadioButton("Label 2")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton2)
        self.groupBox.layout().addWidget(self.radioButton2)

        self.radioButton3 = QRadioButton("Label 3")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton3)
        self.groupBox.layout().addWidget(self.radioButton3)

        self.radioButton4 = QRadioButton("Label 4")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radioButton4)
        self.groupBox.layout().addWidget(self.radioButton4)

        self.toggleButton = QPushButton("Toggle Radio Button", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.toggleButton)
        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(self.toggleRadioButton)

    def toggleRadioButton(self):
        for button in self.buttonGroup.buttons():
            button.setChecked(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

In this updated code, a QButtonGroup is created (self.buttonGroup) to manage the radio buttons. The buttons are added to the group using the addButton method. By setting setExclusive(False), multiple buttons can be unchecked at the same time. In the toggleRadioButton function, each button in the group is iterated over, and setChecked(False) is called to clear the selection.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: ChatGPT has a distinctive and repetitive writing style.

Comment: @DavidW: Yes, it is supported by the presence of a very terse writing style before December 2022, full of spelling mistakes and left out punctuation. Low-quality content comes back to haunt them.